# How can I delete 1,000 rows with EF6?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework 6.

I have a table with test information called Tests. I am deleting 
rows from this table by first getting a list of the tests, doing 
a delete for each and then a commit.

```
   var testList = _testService.GetTests(1, userId).ToList();
   testList.ForEach(_obj => _uow.Tests.Delete(_obj));
   _uow.Commit();
```

I have another table with question information called Questions. 
I would like to do the same but there are over 1000 rows in this
table. If I list them all and then do 1,000 deletes will this 
not be very efficient.

This deletion of questions does not happen very often. Does 
anyone have a suggestion as to how I could do this. Should I do
1,000 deletes. Is it normal to do this kind of thing using EF?

Comment: It is also possible to delete an object without retrieving it - with some caveats - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/03/27/tip-9-deleting-an-object-without-retrieving-it.aspx

Answer (score 96, accepted):

**Edit: Modern Answer for EF Core 7 and above**

EF Core introduced some bulk operations in release 7.0, `.ExecuteDelete()`, `.ExecuteDeleteAsync()`, `.ExecuteUpdate()` and `.ExecuteUpdateAsync()`.

For the problem OP referenced, the updated code would be

```
await db.Tests
.Where(x=>*your where clause)
.ExecuteDeleteAsync()
```

This does not fetch any data to your server and does not issue N delete statements.  Be aware that this is also outside the realm of the Change Tracker and executes immediately, so use caution and/or wrap in a DB Transaction

**Original Answer**

EF 6 as far as I know introduced the .RemoveRange() option on your DbContext.  So in short, you can do something like the following:

```
var db = new MyDbContext();
var itemsToDelete = db.MyTable.Where(x=>!x.active);
db.MyTable.RemoveRange(itemsToDelete);
db.SaveChanges();
```

So instead of having to do any type of `foreach`, you can utilize this new extension method. With your Unit Of Work context, you could have an overload of your `Delete` method that takes an IEnumerable (?*) instead of a single `Test` object like your current method.  This new overload should invoke the `RemoveRange()` function on the DbContext.

?* - It depends on what `GetTests()` returns, but I think `IEnumerable<>` covers both an `IList<>` and an `IQueryable<>`

**Edit**

A couple of comments.  First, I would not call `.ToList()` before issuing the `RemoveRange` as you do not want to actually fetch the items to your service.  This should help cut down on some performance times.  Second, you are right, kind of, that you will still issue 1000 delete statements.  However, the performance gains come from not calling the ChangeTracker in EF for each individual item you are removing from the `DbSet`.  From [MSDN magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn532202.aspx):

> AddRange and RemoveRange As mentioned earlier, AddRange and
> RemoveRange are contributions from community member Zorrilla. Each
> method takes as its parameter an enumerable of a single entity type.
> In the first code sample in the sharing DbTransactions section, I used
> AddRange when I passed in an array of Casino instances:
>
> context.Casinos.AddRange(new[] { casino1, casino2 }); These methods
> execute much faster than adding or removing a single object at a time
> because, by default, Entity Framework calls DetectChanges in each Add
> and Remove method. With the Range methods, you can handle multiple
> objects while DetectChanges is called only once, improving performance
> dramatically. I’ve tested this using five, 50, 500, 5,000 and even
> 50,000 objects and, at least in my scenario, there’s no limit to the
> size of the array—and it’s impressively fast! Keep in mind that this
> improvement is only relevant in getting the context to act on the
> objects, and has no bearing on SaveChanges. Calling SaveChanges still
> executes just one database command at a time. So while you can quickly
> add 50,000 objects into a context, you’ll still get 50,000 insert
> commands executed individually when you call SaveChanges—probably not
> something you want to do in a real system.
>
> On the flip side of this, there were long discussions about
> implementing support for bulk operations without requiring objects to
> be tracked by EF (bit.ly/16tMHw4), and for batch operations to enable
> sending multiple commands together in a single call to the database
> (bit.ly/PegT17). Neither feature made it into the initial EF6 release,
> but both are important and slated for a future release.

If you truly want to only issue a single database command, either a stored procedure of using raw SQL statements would be the way to go since EntityFramework does not support bulk transactions.  However, using the `RemoveRange` and `AddRange` items (especially if, as you said, are infrequent) will save you a lot of time compared to calling `Remove()` in a foreach loop.

Comment: This seems like a good option but I'm not clear how it works. I have a feeling that it will still issue 1000 deletes against the database.

Comment: @SamanthaJ - I added some more detail about how this actually works.  You are correct, however, because the method is optimized, you will see performance gains over the foreach method.  If you only want one command, you are relegated to stored procedures or creating your own SQL syntax and sending to the server.

Answer (score 14):

Built in Entity Framework **.RemoveRange()**  method, still Fetches the Entries on memory , and issues **X** deletes looping though all of them.

If you don't want to write Any SQL for Deletion *especially when selecting which entities to delete is complex*

**[Entity Framework Plus Library](http://entityframework-plus.net/)** offers **batch delete-update** methods issuing only one single command.

```
// Deleting
context.Users
  .Where(u => u.FirstName == "firstname")
  .Delete();
```

> A current limitations of the Entity Framework is that in order to update or delete an entity you have to first retrieve it into memory. Now in most scenarios this is just fine. There are however some senerios where performance would suffer. Also, for single deletes, the object must be retrieved before it can be deleted requiring two calls to the database. Batch update and delete eliminates the need to retrieve and load an entity before modifying it.

Comment: Just an FYI since I get messages on this Q&A pretty frequently...I just went and took and look at that library and I think some caution should be used.  It has not been updated since July 2015 and has 117 open issues currently.  I am not sure it is still being maintained.

Comment: this concerns me to, perhaps they are now contributing directly to EF now thats is open source?

Comment: Just to help others who may want to go down the EF-Plus route; they have re-vamped working on it and it was updated 5 days ago. Seems like it's back in business of being maintained. https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus

Answer (score 6):

I have made some test using EF6 and Sql Server Profiler

**Using .RemoveRange()**

It first fetch all record to delete from database

> exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
>       [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
>       [Extent1].[IdOrder] AS [IdOrder], 
>       [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
>       [Extent1].[Partita] AS [Partita], 
>       FROM [dbo].[MyTable] AS [Extent1]
>       WHERE [Extent1].[IdOrder] = @p__linq__0',N'@p__linq__0
>   varchar(8000)',@p__linq__0='0cb41f32-7ccb-426a-a159-b85a4ff64c29'

Then it fire N delete command to database

> exec sp_executesql N'DELETE [dbo].[MyTable] WHERE ([Id] = @0)',N'@0
>   varchar(50)',@0='ffea29aa-8ba5-4ac9-871b-3f5979180006'
>
> X 1000 times

This happends also using and IQueriable

**Using Entity Framework Extended Library**

It fire only one command to database

> exec sp_executesql N'DELETE [dbo].[MyTable] FROM [dbo].[MyTable] AS
>   j0 INNER JOIN ( SELECT 1 AS [C1], [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id] FROM
>   [dbo].[MyTable] AS [Extent1] WHERE [Extent1].[IdOrder] = @p__linq__0)
>   AS j1 ON (j0.[Id] = j1.[Id])',N'@p__linq__0
>   nvarchar(36)',@p__linq__0=N'0cb41f32-7ccb-426a-a159-b85a4ff64c29'

Comment: As noted in the answer above, your testing confirms that EF does not do bulk transactions.  I still share my concerns using the EF extended library as it still has not been updated since July 2015 and now has ~145 unresolved reported issues.  IMHO, the best method would still be to either call a stored procedure or have EF execute the SQL statement that you want directly such as `ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE myColumn = someValue");` Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592907%28v=vs.113%29.aspx

Comment: I agree with you. I'm scarred that for some reason this extension library will produce a incorrect translation in sql and will delete wrong records.

Answer (score 3):

**Update to EF 7**

Now **EF** supports batch update and delete:

**Bulk Delete**

```cs
context.Books
           .Where(b => b.Name == "somenames")
           .ExecuteDelete();
```

**Bulk Update**

```cs
context.Books
           .Where(b => b.Name == "anothername")
           .ExecuteUpdate(s => s
                        .SetProperty(b => b.Name, b => b.Name + "updated");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    db.TBLName.RemoveRange(db.TBLName.Where(s => s.ID > 0));
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```