# Entity Framework remove a number of records

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Entity Framework delete a number of records

```
using (Galway__Entities db = new Galway__Entities())
{
    DateTime RemovableDate = new DateTime();

    List<PROJ_ACCS_StockControl_DeletedPLURecord> DeletedPLURecords = db.PROJ_ACCS_StockControl_DeletedPLURecord.Where(x => x.TimeStamp <= RemovableDate).ToList();

    db.??????
    //so I delete the list all at once or use a foreach and run round each record?
    //how do I delete each singular record if this is the case then.
}
```

Comment: If you are using EF6, check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21568479/how-can-i-delete-1-000-rows-with-ef6). There is suggested to use `RemoveRange` method.

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
DeletedPLURecords.ForEach(element => db.PROJ_ACCS_StockControl_DeletedPLURecord.Remove(element));
db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 using (Galway__Entities db = new Galway__Entities())
    {
      DateTime RemovableDate = new DateTime();
      List<PROJ_ACCS_StockControl_DeletedPLURecord> DeletedPLURecords = db.PROJ_ACCS_StockControl_DeletedPLURecord.Where(x => x.TimeStamp <= RemovableDate).ToList();

      foreach (var item in DeletedPLURecords)
      {
          var e = db.PROJ_ACCS_StockControl_DeletedPLURecord.Find(item.Id);
          if (e != null)
          {
               Db.PROJ_ACCS_StockControl_DeletedPLURecord.Remove(e);
          }
      }
      db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

currently to remove multiple records you need to first get records in memory then remove them. 
another solution is that you can use [EntityFramework.Extended](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended) library to make this a single request process. like

```
....
db.PROJ_ACCS_StockControl_DeletedPLURecord.Where(x => x.TimeStamp <= RemovableDate).Delete();
```