# EntityFramework database batch delete

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

How to batch delete data in DB with Entity Framework.
This my C# code,and now it work very slow.
Is that because it was deleted only one row a time?
How to delete it faster.
Now,20K rows deleting need 30 min.

```
        var ts = from t in db.MyTasks
                 where t.MyTaskID == id
                 select t;
        var sjs = from t in ts
                  from s in t.Comments
                  where s.CommentJobs.Count() > 0
                  select s;
        var ss = from t in ts
                 from s in t.Comments
                 select s;
        sjs.ToList().ForEach(o => {
            db.CommentJobs.RemoveRange(o.CommentJobs);
        });
        db.Comments.RemoveRange(ss);
        db.MyTasks.RemoveRange(ts);
        db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Which version of EF ?

Comment: If EF6 + you can use the new RemoveRange() method ...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21568479/how-can-i-delete-1-000-rows-with-ef6 which should speed things up nicely and negate the need of 'jumping out of the model' and using something like SqlQuery().

Comment: @Paul Zahra -My EF version is 6.1.3.And I have already using RemoveRange() in my code.But it is still very slow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869209/bulk-deleting-in-linq-to-entities

Comment: RemoveRange() won't really help with performance; it is primarily for programming convenience.  There is something called EntityFramework.Extended (https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended) that supposedly does batch deletes.  I have never used it but you might want to check it out.

Comment: @Jeff Prince This EntityFramework.Extended really works. It can delete 20K rows in 2sec. And if this @ can make StackOverflow Site sending you a notification,please give me a message.I am a fresh about this site,dont know how to reply a comment.Thank you.

Comment: @Yizhi.  Cool, I'm glad it worked out for you.  I am going to have to give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

For bulk operations like this, you can use SqlQuery() method.