# EntityFramework 6.0 generating one DELETE per row

Tags: c#, entity-framework, delete-row

I'm deleting about 5000 rows of my table on a clustered index, and EF takes almost 30 seconds to do it.

Logging the generated SQL shows it's doing one delete for every row:

```
DELETE [dbo].[Table]
WHERE ([ColumnID] = @0)
```

So there are 5000 transactions in total.

I've tried calling SaveChanges() in batches, but this doesn't appear to improve performance much, or change the above behaviour.

```
//loop
{
    //get batch
    db.Table.RemoveRange(batch);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

I have looked at some other questions which point out this flaw of delete commands executed per row, but no suggestion is made afterwards:
[How do I delete multiple rows in Entity Framework (without foreach)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519866/how-do-i-delete-multiple-rows-in-entity-framework-without-foreach)

Is there any way of stopping EF executing one command per row? I'd like to avoid inline SQL if possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfourtunately that is the normal behavior of `RemoveRange` method. You can see the answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21568479/how-can-i-delete-1-000-rows-with-ef6) for more details (check quoted text).

One option could be using [EntityFramework Extended Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.Extended) nuget package, which allows you create a batch to delete the rows in one round trip:

```
 //delete all rows where FirstName matches
 db.Table
.Where(u => u.FirstName == "firstname")// just an example
.Delete();
```

If you don't want to use another 3rd party library, always you have the option of execute a raw sql stamement:

```
db.ExecuteStoreCommand("DELETE FROM Table WHERE FirstName = {0}", firstname);
```

But I think you are pursuing the first solution ;).

Comment: I'd heard some negative feedback regarding EntityFramework Extended Library, but I gave this a go and it was SUBSTANTIALLY faster.

In my case at least - it's a great shout!