# How to delete multiple rows in ASP .NET Core from a table in relation one-to-many at once?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to delete several records from the `Locations` table at once. However, I get an exception after the second pass of the foreach loop. There is also a `RemoveRange` method, but it takes `index` and `count`, but in this case, I don't have these parameters to use this method. How can I in this case remove several items at once from a table that is in relation one-to-many?

```
public async Task RemoveMultipleLocations(int id, IEnumerable<int> locationsIds)
{
   var profile = await context.AlertProfiles.Include(x => x.Locations).FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);

   var existing = profile.Locations.Where(x => locationsIds.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
   if(existing != null)
   {
         foreach(var ex in existing)
         {
              profile.Locations.Remove(ex);
         }
         profile.ModifiedDate = DateTimeOffset.Now;
         await context.SaveChangesAsync();
   }
}
```

[image: RemoveRange]

Comment: Please don't post images when text is possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I delete multiple rows in Entity Framework Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41960215/how-do-i-delete-multiple-rows-in-entity-framework-core)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete the data from DB, I think the following code and references will be useful.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.removerange?view=efcore-5.0

[How can I delete 1,000 rows with EF6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21568479/how-can-i-delete-1-000-rows-with-ef6)

You can edit your code this way.

```
public async Task RemoveMultipleLocations(int id, IEnumerable<int> locationsIds)
{
   var profile = await context.AlertProfiles.Include(x => x.Locations).FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);

   var existing = profile.Locations.Where(x => locationsIds.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
   if(existing.Any())
   {
         context.Locations.RemoveRange(existing);         
         await context.SaveChangesAsync();
   }
}
```

Since you have converted the" Location " list to ToList (), you do not need to check null. You can check with Any() method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (instead of profile.Locations use context.Locations):

```
var profile= await context.Profiles
                         .Include(x => x.Location)
                         .Where(x=>x.Id==id)
                         .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

var existing = profile.Locations.Where(x => locationsIds.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
if(existing != null){
 context.Locations.RemoveRange(existing);
 context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Or if Location is only  a navigate property:

```
if(existing != null)
{
foreach(var location in existing)
 context.Entry(location).State = EntityState.Deleted;
}
 context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I can't pass 'existing' into RemoveRange. It only accepts 'index' and 'count' as parameters, as I wrote in the question.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand why you don't have index and count. Did you try to remove range and what error did you get?

Comment: I updated the question with a screenshot (RemoveRange problem).

Comment: If I insert existing.Clear() instead of this loop (or RemoveRange), the records in the database remain unremoved.

Answer (score 0):

As you have already found out, `RemoveRange` expects a start index and a count. But that's not difficult to obtain:

```
existing.RemoveRange(0, existing.Count())
```

you do not even need a loop, as you have already queried the records you intend to remove.