# Detach Entity Collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Well, i have a Model with a collection saving changes in a loop structure

```cs
foreach(Customer objCustomer in listCustomer)
{
    try
    {
        db.Customer.Add(objCustomer);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        db.Entry(objCustomer).State = EntityState.Detach;
    }
}
```

When it throws me any exception in a collection related to entity, the next ones keeps throwing exceptions.

I tried to detach the entire collection but it didn't work

```
foreach(Customer objCustomer in listCustomer)
{
    try
    {
        db.Customer.Add(objCustomer);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < objCustomer.Address; i++)
        {
            db.Entry(objCustomer.Address[i]).State = EntityState.Detach;
        }
        db.Entry(objCustomer).State = EntityState.Detach;
    }
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: 1. I don't think you can "detach" the entity if the "add" operation failed. 2. I'm guessing that you are actually trying to update an existing customer but are incorrectly adding it to the database?

Comment: Actually i'm trying add if not exists and update if exists

Comment: What exception you got ?!

Comment: DbValidation exception in collection Address, after the first it keeps throwing the same exception for all entities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why but it works, i used like it refers in this post

[EntityCollection Clear() and Remove() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875439/entitycollection-clear-and-remove-methods)

`objCustomer.Address.ToList().ForEach(x => db.Entry(x).State = EntityState.Detached);`

It is almost as i did before using "for"

Thanks anyway everyone

Answer (score 0):

i thought that the exception of second code maybe has been never occurred?

In addition，your code has any transaction ?

Comment: I imagine that the transaction open when i use 

using (Context db = new Context){}

Answer (score 0):

Try this? Warning not tested!

```
using(var db = new Context())
{

    foreach(Customer objCustomer in listCustomer)
    {
         var exists = db.Customer.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CustomerID == objCustomer.CustomerID;

         if( exists = null)
         {
            db.Customer.Add(objCustomer);

         }
         else
         {
            db.Entry(objCustomer).State = EntityState.Modified;
         }
         db.SaveChanges();

    }

}
```

Comment: It did not work "The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key"