# how to delete items using entity framework

Tags: entity-framework

To say I had `proxy class` and `Lazyloading` both disabled. and I two objects with a `many to many` relation. When coming to delete a record, I had the codes:

```
public void DeleteUser(List<int> ids)
{
    using (var dbContext = new AccountDbContext())
    {
        dbContext.Users.Include("Roles").Where(u => ids.Contains(u.ID)).ToList().ForEach(a => { 
            //a.Roles.Clear(); 
            //dbContext.Users.Remove(a); 
            dbContext.Delete(a);
        });
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

It looks like `dbContext.Delete(user)` will  delete the `Roles` related to the `user`[which in the database a many to many record is deleted ]. As I thought `cascade delete` is enabled. So can I say `user.Roles.Clear();` is totally unnecessary here?  And when should I implement a `Clear` method?

Comment: Take a look at this `Clear` remove reference it doesn't delete the objects http://stackoverflow.com/a/3875502/1876572

Comment: If cascade delete is enabled on the FK relationship in DB, then calling Clear() is not necessary, since the clearing is done on the DB level.